# pagespeed module and css

Tags: css, google-chrome, pagespeed

I have a wordpress site in Google cloud.

Sometimes Chrome doesn't load "rtl" css which make me site goes from RTL to LTR

Also, my logo disappears sometimes and the link turned from ".png file" to "png.pagespeed.ic.nIKFiRDINy.webp"

I did some search and I found the problem is "pagespeed module".

I use this line to flush the PageSpeed cache, and it works, but I'm tired doing that and I want to fix it.

"sudo touch /opt/bitnami/apache2/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush"

anyone knows how to fix it once and for all?

Comment: here is my website link:https://www.195sports.com

Comment: update.. no one?